Swagger Core added html tags to API name and description in swagger.json file after upgrade to newer version
After upgrading to Swagger Core 2.2.11 and using SAP Cloud swaggerintegration extension, all endpoints, names, and params are wrapped in html tags.


To generate the swagger description, the following annotations are used in my controller classes.
@Tag(name = "Address")
@Operation(operationId = "getAddresses", summary = "Get customer's addresses", description = "Returns customer's addresses.")
@Parameter(
    name = "titleCode",
    description = "Customer's title code. Customer's title code. For a list of codes, see /{baseSiteId}/titles resource",
    required = false,
    schema = @Schema(type = "string"),
    in = ParameterIn.QUERY
    )


Any ideas about what might be wrong?
Honestly have no idea what to try out. Was doing everything according to SAP migration guide.
Thanks!
